# Scroll table in table with button

Tags: html, jquery

I have a HTML table in bigger table and this inner table has a scroll bar.

How can I make buttons that scrolls up or down in inner table?

below is my code snippet

```
script part...

<script>
function scroll(p) {
    var offset = $('#' + p).offset();
    $('.wapper').animate({scrollTop: offset.top}, 400)
};
</script>

cell in inner table...
            <td style="width: 190px;">
                <button onclick="scroll('up')">up</button>
                <div class="wapper">
                    <table id="category" class="table--inner">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="top"></div>
                                <img src="{% static 'an image' %}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ...
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="bottom"></div>
                                <img src="{% static 'another image' %}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <button onclick="scroll('bottom')">down</button>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you need to do:

1. Swap your 2 scroll buttons and change the name of your function to something, just don't use `scroll`.
2. Add div container for your inner table and buttons (we'll use this container for scrolling).
3. Add css to your container.

Script:

```html
    <script>
            function scrollMe(el, p) {
                var offset =
                    p === 'up' ? 0 : $(el).closest('.td-container')[0].scrollHeight; // this is to get the parent container's scroll height
                $('.td-container').animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 400);
            }
    </script>
```

HTML

```html
cell in inner table...
            <td style="width: 190px;">
                <div class="td-container">
                <button onclick="scrollMe(this, 'bottom')">Scroll Down</button>
                <div class="wapper">
                    <table id="category" class="table--inner">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="top"></div>
                                <img src="{% static 'an image' %}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ...
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div id="bottom"></div>
                                <img src="{% static 'another image' %}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <button onclick="scrollMe(this, 'up')">Scroll Up</button>
                </div>
            </td>
```

CSS style for td-container

```css
.td-container {
  max-height: 40px;  // set preferred max-height of container to scroll
  overflow-y: auto;  // set scroll behavior to auto
}
```